# What are some safe ways to play a video file that was downloaded from the internet?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, video

I would like to know what are some safe and easy ways to play a media (in particular, video) file that I downloaded from the internet, from an untrusted source. I know that if I use an open-source media player, like VLC, one could craft the media file in such a way to [exploit a vulnerability](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-5842/product_id-9978/Videolan-Vlc-Media-Player.html) in the media player and possibly hijack my computer. Would the Windows **Movies & TV** app be safer than VLC in principle, since it's not open-source? Are there any media players designed with security in mind?

Related question: [How to handle media files from untrusted sources?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110644/how-to-handle-media-files-from-untrusted-sources?rq=1)

Comment: Are you asking if open source is more secure than closed source? That's a separate question.

Comment: "Are there any media players designed with security in mind?" ends up being a product recommendation, which is off-topic.

Comment: Aside from those two questions, you appear to be asking the same thing in the question you linked and the answer is the same: use a media player that is up-to-date and play them in a container/VM/sandbox.,